# How to store an array of images from SDWebImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdwebimage

```
_imags = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: 
    sd_setImageWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://api.androidhive.info/json/movies/1.jpg"]
    placeholderImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"download.jpeg"], nil ];
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review [ask] and you can [edit] your question with more details what you are trying to do.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.